# Truncation may occur due to retrieving data from column description with a length of 1024 to data flow column "description" with a length of 64

Tags: ssis, package, etl

Getting the below error while running the SSIS packages

> Truncation may occur due to retrieving data from database column
> "description" with a length of 1024 to data flow column "description"
> with a length of 64.

I am expeting the data to process one table to another table to copy from SSIS. as the schema same ideally data has to pass bur getting this exception message

Comment: So that's a warning "*may* occur" Is it actually erroring on execution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Truncation may occur due to retrieving data from database column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501038/warning-truncation-may-occur-due-to-retrieving-data-from-database-column)